# Trying to problem solve "Fatal Errors" and "No Such File or Directory"

Tags: laravel, laravel-valet

I'm at a total loss here.

All I am trying to do is clone a Laravel Project onto my local mac machine and I've probably spent 10 - 12 hours on this and I keep getting the same errors over and over.

I've tried Homestead, MAMP and now I am on Valet.

I can load the app but all the links are broken so the CSS and JS don't load.

After I clone (via bitbucket) the project I hit the test site on my machine and I get this error:

```
Warning: require(/Users/henry/sites/nestdb2017/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/henry/sites/nestdb2017/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/Users/henry/sites/nestdb2017/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.9_1/share/php/pear') in /Users/henry/sites/nestdb2017/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

The next thing I do is I try to install the missing vendor files by doing this:

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

which then throw the broken links.

Literally I'm going to have to throw the towel in here...

It's unbelievable how hard this is.

Is it because the source files are corrupt in the first instance??

Comment: did you try `composer install` after cloning the application.

Comment: What is the error you get when you do `composer install` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
composer install

php artisan clear-compiled
```

Then

```
composer dumpautoload
```

Tell us the results.